# How can I set the font size in wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

The manual only shows how to set the header and footer font size. How do I set the body font size? http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: header and footer are generated by wkhtmltopdf, so you can adjust their font size, body is converted from HTML to pdf with original settings, I don't think you can change its font size in the tool.

Comment: Yes, I just found I can set it with css in the html. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @giorgio79 it's better to answer your question so others can use it as a source imo

Answer (score 1):

Just found meanwhile that wkhtmltopdf respects css font sizes and families set for classes, ids, etc.